# Should I be keeping references to Azure CloudTableClient/CloudTable?

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-table-storage

I'm struggling to find some real guidance on whether I should share instances of the Azure Table Storage set of objects in my ASP.Net WebAPI application.

For completeness, retrieving an entity from Table Storage looks like the below.

When integrating something like this in a data layer where I have a single "Repository" instance shared across an application, is it safe to keep a reference to the `CloudTable` - sharing it with future operations - or should I be recreating the `CloudTable` via `tableClient.GetTableReference` for each operation? Or perhaps even recreating the `CloudTableClient` for each operation?

```
// Retrieve the storage account from the connection string.
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
    CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

// Create the table client.
CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

// Create the CloudTable object that represents the "people" table.
CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("people");

// Create a retrieve operation that takes a customer entity.
TableOperation retrieveOperation = TableOperation.Retrieve<CustomerEntity>("Smith", "Ben");

// Execute the retrieve operation.
TableResult retrievedResult = table.Execute(retrieveOperation);

// Print the phone number of the result.
if (retrievedResult.Result != null)
   Console.WriteLine(((CustomerEntity)retrievedResult.Result).PhoneNumber);
else
   Console.WriteLine("The phone number could not be retrieved.");
```

As an aside, any resources / must-reads which would help me answer this or similar in future are extremely welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharing instances of your objects should be fine. If you're trying to use different authentication/configuration for different tables then you should have more instances.

Comment: Can you expand on this? Unfortunately, the only documentation I can find is the typical "Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe." This would imply that one is required to recreate the entire set of objects for each request.